# How to convince an anti-rawlsian of the pertinence of the "veil of ignorance" condition?

Tags: political-philosophy, justice, rawls, social-contract

My question is not about the contractarian methodology adopted by Rawls, but specfically about the "veil of ignorance" condition.

How to articulate precisely the moral intuition that is behind this requirement?

An idea that comes immediately is that supposing that the persons involved in the choice of the principles of justice do not know their particular conditions makes sure that their choice will be  impartial.

Though I have read Rawls' *Theory Of Justice* ( some years ago  have to say) , I cannot fully explain to myself the reasons justifying this requirement. Which does not mean I'm unable to appreciate the admirable power of its consequences.

In brief, how to convince an anti-rawlsian that the veil of ignorance is a pertinent condition of the social contract?

Comment: One is morally obliged to minimize the effect of her personal biases and prejudices when making rules for everybody (fairness principle). And the safest way to do it is to procedurally make selfish motivations themselves favor fairness (rather than rely on moral scruples). That's the reason. Another nice illustration of it is [divide and choose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_choose): one person cuts the cake in two, the other chooses her slice first. The divider is selfishly motivated to be as fair as possible, it is the veil of ignorance in miniature.

Comment: As if someone needs many more experiments to prove that... but some more were done https://www.pnas.org/content/116/48/23989

Comment: For a more precise answer, you should clarify what you mean by "anti-rawlsian " though. Because a lot of those who reject the principle don't really argue from anything but a selfish perspective, e.g. "I'm very rich, so why should I care about the poor? Thus the best social contract framework is one that ensures that I keep my riches." A slightly different one, more likely to be actually expressed in politics is the famous "trickle down".

Comment: N.B. for more philosophical/theoretical arguments  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/original-position/#ArgForPriJusOriPos A point to note from there is that the VoI is reached if parties agree this is the best outcome for everyone. Obviously if someone's opinion doesn't matter equally (as it's often the case in real life political contexts), the outcome can be different than agreeing to VoI.

Comment: @Conifold The Rawlsian cake-cutter would first cut the cake, then flip a coin to decide which half they get.

Comment: @causative: Nope. Firstly, that is only a *psychologically* similar construction,  and, more importantly, probabilistic decisions are explicitly excluded in the Original Position. Otherwise, it would be purely about utilitarian selfishness. That's not what the VoI is about, though.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking eh?  the veil of ignorance is about not knowing who in society you will be, is it not?  How do you expect to represent that lack of knowledge without using probability?

Comment: @causative You do not simply not know who you will be in the sense of your economic status, you do not know your gender, ethnicity, intelligence, abilities, education, position, health, anything which allows for selfish bias. But the point is: If you'd think probabilistically, there would be an incitement to utilitarian calculus à la "even if there are only 10% rich people, if I give them enough, I'll take that chance". That's something Rawls wanted to prevent. And that's why they don't know how the above properties are going to be distributed as well. It's about a fair *system*.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking maybe I'm wrong but I thought the exact purpose is that they *would* consider chances like that (and reject them since a 10 pct chance of riches is not worth a 90 pct chance of misery)

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking: Agreed. Which is why Rawls' argument falls on some deaf ears in real life, because e.g. being born rich is not a random event but correlated with the status of parents etc. Some Rawls commentators have called this the "persistent inadequacy of citizens"... So this is why I'm asking the OP to clarify what he means by "anti-Rawlsian". .

Comment: @causative From above SEP article: "What now is the appropriate decision rule to be used to choose principles of justice under conditions of complete uncertainty of probabilities in Rawls’s original position? Rawls argues that, given the enormous gravity of choice in the original position, plus the fact that the choice is not repeatable, it is rational for the parties to follow the maximin strategy" <- he argues against bayesian decision theory.

Comment: @Fizz That is why there should be **no** inheritance of monetary wealth in fair political systems (in the Rawlsian sense) ;) I think it is problematic to say that a political theory is bad because it is counterfactual. And that systematic fairness will probably not allow for richness as contemporary systems do is not that surprising, really. It is telling that the "trickle down" Chicago School of neoliberalism (which has been shown to be nonsense empirically) argued most fiercely against Rawls.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking the appropriate decision rule may be minimax according to Rawls, but that doesn't mean you aren't faced with a probabilistic choice.  The use of probability does not imply the use of any particular decision rule.

Comment: @causative Equal probabilities appear in Harsanyi's version of the veil, not Rawls's. Rawls, unlike Harsanyi, was anti-utilitarian, and in his scheme the probabilities are unknown/undefined, not equal, see Fizz's first link. Indeed, probabilities are moot if one does not aim at maximizing utility. But even in Harsanyi's scheme one has equal probability of being the divider or the chooser when the rules for the cutting are set up *beforehand*. There is no coin flipping when they are applied, i.e. *after* the cutting.

Comment: @Conifold alright.  It still sounds like this conflates the decision rule (utilitarianism) with the model of uncertainty (probability).  You can have probability without utilitarianism.  Any time you say one has no knowledge of an outcome, this can only be interpreted as a uniform distribution over possible outcomes, whether Rawls translates it into those terms or not.  Probability is a numerical representation of an individual's lack of knowledge about an outcome.

Comment: @Conifold in fact what could it mean to have no knowledge of an outcome?  It cannot just mean that no outcome can be deduced with certainty, because even just a suspicion for one outcome over others would not be called "no knowledge."  It must mean that we assign credence to the different outcomes exactly equally.  How else can this be interpreted, aside from equal probabilities?  It just isn't meaningful to say "no knowledge" if one refuses this interpretation.

Comment: @causative That one has no knowledge of an outcome does not translate into any distribution over possible outcomes, let alone a uniform one. Setting the prior by the [principle of indifference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference) is often undesirable in Bayesian inference, and meaningless on frequency interpretations, see also [Knightian uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knightian_uncertainty). One may have no clue as to possible outcomes (sample space), the outcomes may have no stable frequencies, etc. Probability is of limited use as a measure of ignorance.

Comment: @Conifold Whenever setting the prior by the principle of indifference is undesirable, it's *precisely because* we often do not have a perfect lack of knowledge about the outcomes.  When we do have a perfect lack of knowledge there is no other choice.  With respect to the veil of ignorance we do know the outcomes; you will be one of the people in the society.  (See the Solomonoff universal prior if you really didn't know, but in this case we do.)  The frequentist interpretation is irrelevant since we're talking about a person's lack of subjective knowledge.

Comment: @Conifold Knightian uncertainty has its place, though it certainly can be slotted neatly into the Bayesian perspective.  But in this case Knightian uncertainty does not apply, since we're explicitly giving the set of outcomes (the people in the society) and explicitly saying there is no knowledge of the outcomes.  Those two things mean that we can easily and perfectly quantify the probability, which means there is no Knightian uncertainty.

Comment: @causative Of course there are other choices, set a more intelligent prior if the lack is indeed imperfect or do not use Bayesian scheme at all. Which makes more sense here since there is no updating and probabilities are moot to Rawls's reasoning anyway. The outcomes are not people but their social statuses, which we have no clear idea about because Rawls does not prescribe any social structure in particular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120891/discussion-between-causative-and-conifold).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major part of Rawls' argument here depends on a contrast with the sympathetic-spectator model of impartiality. Rawls goes to great lengths to point out the difficulty with resolving the question, "How would the spectator judge?" especially considering that we have much more real-life experience with a lack of knowledge than with the relative omniscience attributed to such a spectator.

Doubtless(!) Rawls would not put his point so strictly, but you could frame the appeal to the veil of ignorance as either/or: to model impartiality, you can assume a sympathetic spectator, or you can assume a veil of ignorance. Again, the point is not strict since as Rawls argues, it's possible that deductions from either model might end up lining up.

Answer (score -1):

I subscribe to Socrates’ notion that, knowledge is the only virtue.

Unlike Rawl’s theories, especially VoI, Socrates position is simple and lacks nuances. Which, I think, leaves us with two possibilities:

1. The father of Philosophy was incredibly naive
2. His position stems from deep insights into human nature — the insights that Rawl was lacking.

I think 2) makes more sense, aside from the obvious reason, because we all know what makes ignorance preferable — it often is when the knowledge is incomplete.

“The only thing worse than the outright lies is a half-truth”, and in Rawl’s theories half-truth is abundant. E.g. he defined rationality not by stating what it is, but by offering vague accounts of how it would manifest itself in some circumstances.

So that’s my objection to VoI — it’s a band-aid meant to adjust for... lacking key bits of knowledge — like the role of happiness in our lives (it’s not a reward, but our first moral duty before ourselves and others).

Or being clear about the dynamics of a fight, when you and your opponent always fight on the same side against fear, your common enemy — their fear, as well as your own. There are tons of similarly important insights, which, if taken into account, would make the whole idea of justice and the social contract simply irrelevant. With enough knowledge of how things really work between us, simply acting out of enlightened self-interest would produce morally perfect behavior.

Or in Socrates' words, “*Once a man knows good from evil, nothing on earth can compel him to act against that knowledge.*”

The ultimate goal, therefore, is to uncover the whole truth, to keep asking why and looking for explanations until you see the whole picture, knowing yourself, others, the meaning of life and the word we share.

Comment: Not an answer to the question. Also, it is full of ignorance regarding Rawls. The people in the Original Position (behind the veil of ignorance) know a great deal about the world, morals, and psychology. Actually, much more than most people. That is the basis of their ability to conceive fair, **working, and stable** systems.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking > *"The people in the Original Position...  know a great deal about the world..."* -- in that case, why don't they talk to me?

Comment: For someone who adheres to the views of what probably is nothing more but a literary device and repeatedly states that we need to seek knowledge, it is surprising how little you know (or understand) of the philosophers you argue against. This answer is telling since it shows that you do not even know how limited the ignorance in that model is, nor basic facts about human psychology it tries to address.

Comment: i'm sure that is not the only thing you find surprising about me... speaking of which -- FYI, there is an objective test that will show who, between us two, is a real human being, and who only pretends to be one... interested?

Comment: Oh, so you presume that only one of us can be "a real human being" and the other one necessarily "only pretends"? Not very Socratic. I am listening.